# Xamarin white screen in local machine

Tags: xamarin

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKAqv.jpg)

Hello,
I have a problem with Xamarin, when i run program i see only white screen, just like on picture. 
MainPage.xaml.cs have this code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Xamarin.Forms;
namespace Hello
{
public class App : Application
{
    public App()
        { // The root page of your application 
            MainPage = new ContentPage
            {
                Content = new StackLayout
                {
                    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                    Children = {
                        new Label {
                            HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
                            Text = "Welcome to Xamarin Forms!"
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
        }
        protected override void OnStart()
        {
            // Handle when your app starts 
        }
        protected override void OnSleep()
        {
            // Handle when your app sleeps 
        } 
        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            // Handle when your app resumes 
        }
    }
}
```

I take this code from "Creating Mobile Apps with Xamarin Forms", somebody know what is wrong with this program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write your code in **Shared project's** `App.xaml.cs` class which is partial class. The code above you are showing is not partial class. Probably, as your screenshot showing you have written App class code in Main.axml.cs file

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

[assembly: XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
namespace App
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //MainPage = new MainPage();
            MainPage = new ContentPage
            {
                Content = new StackLayout
                {
                    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                    Children =
                    {
                        new Label
                        {
                            HorizontalTextAlignment=TextAlignment.Center,
                            Text="Welcome to xamarin forms"
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```